# Run Code error in Access Macro

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to make a macro in Access that will run VBA code.  I trying am using the RunCode command to Run a function that will run a VBA function that I have already created but for some reason it says it can't find it and I am really confused why. I have posted a picture of the macro as well as the code below.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Macro:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUVD9.jpg

Code:

```
Function Totals()

Dim db As Database

Set db = CurrentDb
foldername = CurrentProject.Path & "\GeneralTotals"
deleteTotals = "DELETE * FROM Totals"

totalVerified = "INSERT INTO Totals([TOTAL VERIFIED FORMULARIES], [TOTAL AVAILABLE FOR IMPORT], [TOTAL SHOULD BE IMPORTED], [TOTAL RECENTLY IMPORTED]) " & _
"SELECT A.cnt, B.cnt, C.cnt, D.cnt " & _
"FROM ( " & _
    "SELECT COUNT([FORMULARY ID]) as cnt " & _
    "FROM VerifiedFormularies " & _
") AS A " & _
", ( " & _
    "SELECT COUNT([FORMULARY ID]) as cnt " & _
    "FROM ImportMetricsIDs " & _
") as B " & _
", ( " & _
    "SELECT COUNT([FORMULARY ID]) as cnt " & _
    "FROM ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable " & _
    "WHERE [IMPORTSTATUS]= 'Yes' " & _
") AS C " & _
", ( " & _
    "SELECT COUNT([LATEST]) as cnt " & _
    "FROM VerifiedFormularies " & _
    "WHERE [LATEST]= 'Yes' " & _
") AS D "


db.Execute deleteTotals
db.Execute totalVerified


DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel5, "Totals", foldername

MsgBox ("Totals have been exported to: " & foldername)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue most likely depends on location of trigger event and code placement.

- How are you triggering the RunTotals macro? With an embedded macro
  using the RunMacro action or in VBA using DoCmd.RunMacro?
- Where is the Function Totals() placed? It needs to be behind the form
  triggering the event or in a module.

Finally, you can avoid using separate objects (RunTotals macro and embedded macro) if in your trigger event, you type into the Property sheet event line "=Totals()" Alternatively, you can simply call the function in VBA with the simple line: Totals. But location as explained in second bullet still applies.